# How to create a program that adds subtracts devides and multiplies 2 fractions?

Tags: java, addition, calculator, fractions

first i would like to start saying that i am new to programing and i don t know much. with that said i would appreciate if anyone could help me with my program that it is supposed to read 2 fractions and an operator for example "2/3 + 4/5". i have some of the code done but it still give me an error when i run it here is what i have so far:

```
public class Fraction {

    private static int numer;
    private static int denom;

     public Fraction(int num, int den)
        {
            numer = num;
            denom = den;
            simplify();
        }


    int findGcd(int a, int b)
        { 
        int temp;
            while(b != 0)
            {
                    temp = b;
                    b = a % b;
                    a = temp;
            }
        return a;
    }


    void simplify()
        {
            int gcd = findGcd(numer, denom);
            numer /= gcd;
            denom /= gcd;
        }

    public int getNumer(){
        return numer;
    }

    public int getDenom(){
        return denom;
    }



    Fraction add(Fraction x) {
        Fraction result;

        if (x.getDenom()== getDenom()) {
            result = new Fraction(x.getNumer() + getNumer(), denom);
        } else {
            denom = this.getDenom() * x.getDenom();
            numer = this.getNumer() * x.getDenom() + x.getNumer() * this.getDenom();
            return new Fraction(numer,denom);


        }
        return result;
    }

    public String toString(){
          return (Integer.toString(numer) + "/" +
                     Integer.toString(denom));
    }



    public static void main (String []args){
            Fraction a = new Fraction(1,3);
            Fraction b = new Fraction(4,5);
            System.out.println(a.toString());
            System.out.println(b.toString());
    }
}
```

thank you for your help i really appreciate it.

Comment: What did you read and understood about programming? What is the error messages you are getting? Did your compiler gave any warnings (and did you enable all of them)?

Comment: Well, there doesn't seem any error in your code, when I run it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you making your fields [`static`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)? `static` fields belong to the class as opposed to each instantiation (not what you want here). Try removing the `static` keyword.

On another note, you mentioned that you'd like to read input from the user. You might want to look into using a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for this (in case you don't already know about this handy class).

Once you read the input, something like `2/3 + 4/5`, you can split your string using a space as your delimiter. Now, you can parse a fraction from the first (`2/3`) and third (`4/5`) elements of the newly formed string array, and perform the operation that corresponds to the second element of the array (`+`).

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between `static` variable and `instance` variable.

- Static variable is a class variable which is common for all instances.. So, if you change these variables for one instance, it will be changed for all the instances.
- Instance variable, on the other hand, are specific to each instance.. They are binded to an instance of a class.

That being said.. You need to modify your code a little bit..

Change your `static` variables in your class to `instance` variables..

```
private static int numer;
private static int denom;
```

The above two variables should be instance variables..  So that they are unique for each instance you create for your class..

So, change them to: -

```
private int numer;
private int denom;
```

And for reading user input, `A.R.S` has already given you link to a `valuable` class..

Comment: thanks alot Rohit Jain!! this resolved the issue I was having with my program always using one of the input fractions. thank you again.